# Combine individual messages to 1 output every 15 seconds

Tags: json, azure, azure-stream-analytics

Is it possible to combine separate device messages received every 15 seconds into 1 summarized device message?

For example I want to collect "Temperature","RPM" and "Gauge" messages:

```
Message 1

{
   DeviceId: 1
   Key: "Temperature" 
   Value: 15
}


Message 2   
{
    DeviceId: 1,
    Key: "RPM"
    Value: 2000
}
```

Into:

```
{
  DeviceId: 1,
  Readings:
  {
     "Temperature": 15,
     "RPM": 2000 
     "Gauge": "Unknown" (no value in the 15 seconds window, so unknown)
  }
}
```

EDIT:
Forgot to add, it is expected that if 1 of 3 messages for a device ("Temperature","RPM" and "Gauge") arrives in SA. The other 2 will be likely received within the next 15 seconds. So the SA job should start "collecting" when it sees 1 of the messages. Is a SA job suitable for this or should I look for another solution?

Comment: Hi @Vort, welcome to Stackoverflow. Couple of questions. A) Do you care if the values are duplicated? e.g. "Temperature" : 15, 15, 1, 3.  B) Can you do the summarization on the receiving end / client end?

Comment: A) I would like to avoid duplicates
B) The SA job should trigger an Azure Function, so ideally the summarized values should be present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/reference/lag-azure-stream-analytics?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function. Would look something like this:

```
SELECT 
     DeviceId, [Key], [Value] 
     LAG(reading) OVER (PARTITION BY DeviceId LIMIT DURATION(hour, 1) WHEN reading IS NOT NULL)  
     FROM input
```

LAG allows you to look a specified number of events and then also for a given partition key (in this case I used the DeviceId).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. I have solved this using the SessionWindow.